# How can I add custom values to robots meta tag on specifics ids in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-tags

```
function wporg_wp_robots_add_follow( $robots ) {
unset( $robots['max-image-preview'] );
$robots['noindex'] = true;
$robots['nofollow'] = true;
return $robots;
} 
add_filter( 'wp_robots', 'wporg_wp_robots_add_follow' );
```

I want to make this function work, but only on specific pages selected by ID, To be more specific I want to noy display the robot tag that already set by default in wordpress
<meta name="robots" content="max-image-preview:large,/>
and instead I want to display
 But only on some posts or pages using an array by ID.
This is what I have until now.

```
function wporg_wp_robots_add_follow( $robots ) {
if ( is_single( array (28, 29, 30) ) ) {
unset( $robots['max-image-preview'] );
$robots['noindex'] = true;
$robots['nofollow'] = true;
}
return $robots;
}
add_filter( 'wp_robots', 'wporg_wp_robots_add_follow' );
```

But It's not work. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to pass in the id and check if it is in array.
I hope this can help you at least get the idea.

```html
function wporg_wp_robots_add_follow($robots, $id) {
  $array_ids = array (28, 29, 30);
  if (in_array($id, $array_ids)) {
    unset( $robots['max-image-preview'] );
    $robots['noindex'] = true;
    $robots['nofollow'] = true;
  }
  return $robots;
}
add_filter( 'wp_robots', 'wporg_wp_robots_add_follow' );
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but didn't work, I have this error: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wporg_wp_robots_add_follow(), 1 passed in F:\XAMPP PROYECTOS\htdocs\giantec\aaleyahs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 303 and exactly 2 expected in F:\XAMPP PROYECTOS\htdocs\giantec\aaleyahs\wp-content\themes\Aaleyahs-custom-theme\functions.php:23